# PyInstaller 3.2.1 with Kivy 1.10.0 pyz syntax error and dosn't pack

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller

When using PyInstaller 3.2.1 to pack a Kivy 1.10.0  application written in python 3.6.1 on a windows 10 for the first time following the Kivy.org tutorial on application packaging. When I went to pack the `.spec` file in windows command line I get a syntax error relating to the `pzy` variable. I have looked at both the Kivy support section, the PyInstaller support page and reinstalled both PyInstaller and Kivy using wheels instead of Pycharm. The error message I received is from windows command line is below:

```
92 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
92 INFO: Python: 3.6.1
93 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
95 INFO: UPX is not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 97, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 20
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The `.spec` file I have been using is below:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_deps_minimal, get_deps_all, hookspath, runtime_hooks
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['KivyCalculator\\main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\lukeb\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python\\'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=hookspath(),
             runtime_hooks=runtime_hooks(),
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher
             **get_deps_all()

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, 
    cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='KivyCalculator',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , icon='KivyCalculator\\icon.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,Tree('C:\\Users\\lukeb\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python\\KivyCalculator'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='KivyCalculator')
```

I would be very grateful for any help people could offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you made a typo in the `.spec` file and the file is just Python, so you'll basically end up with this:

```
a = Analysis(...,
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher  # no comma
             **get_deps_all()     # no closing bracket

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,  # bam, syntax error
    cipher=block_cipher)
```